Calling the content of a menu under a pie menu
I am trying to add Blender already made context menu under my custom pie menu.
The problem is that I want to call directly the content of the menu, but I'm getting a menu entry with a sub-menu:

I made a picture edit to show what I want:

This is the code for this example:
import bpy

class VIEW3D_MT_PIE_Test(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Test"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        pie = layout.menu_pie()

        pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="LEFT")
        pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="RIGHT")
        pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="DOWN")
        pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="UP")
        pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="UP LEFT")
        pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="UP RIGHT")
        pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="DOWN LEFT")
        pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="DOWN RIGHT")
        pie.separator()
        pie.separator()

        col = pie.column(align=True)
        gap = col.column(align=True)
        gap.separator()
        gap.scale_y = 5.0
        

        col.separator()
        col.menu("VIEW3D_MT_object_context_menu")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_MT_PIE_Test)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_MT_PIE_Test)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name="VIEW3D_MT_PIE_Test")


I actually went through the documentation again, and found menu_contents.
All I have to do is replace col.menu("VIEW3D_MT_object_context_menu") by col.menu_contents("VIEW3D_MT_object_context_menu").
The style is different that the actual menu, so now I just need to find out how to add a background to this menu that is transparent and how to grab the title of the menu, and how to have the over of sub-menus working without clicking.

EDIT: Also the sub-menu Convert To and Set Origin are acting differently than Mirror, Snap and Parent.
